# How can I lock my apk android file to install only in specific brand device (e.g: manufacturer x but not manufacturer y)?

Tags: android

I need to develop a android and ios app for a customer and need to quote how long time it takes to lock the apk file to only install in their devices to be manufactured, but not sure how and the time consuming (hence the cost to do so..) to come up with this request.
Wondering what are the steps to proceed with that, how complex is that process and how long time it takes.
Any information is appreciated.

Comment: This question doesn't apply to iOS devices. You can be certain that every single iOS device is made by Apple. There are no third party iOS devices. you should edit your question to remove the iOS tag and the references to iOS

Answer (score 0):

There is only one manufacturer of iOS devices. In all likelihood, it is not your customer.

On the Android side, what you want is not possible — you cannot, on your own, create an APK that can only be installed on devices from one manufacturer. An APK can be installed on any compatible device.

The manufacturer could make changes to their Android build that you could leverage, such as the manufacturer adding some custom feature string (e.g., `com.manufacturer.hardware.this.is.so.fake`), which your APK requires via a `<uses-feature>` element. Since other conventional hardware will not have that feature string, your APK will not be able to be installed on that hardware. Custom ROM developers and people who root their devices could add that custom feature string to their own devices, though, and still install your app. But, again, this sort of thing requires the manufacturer to take certain steps (e.g., add this custom feature string).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, quick question regarding to that, what means ROM ?